# javascript only working for one element, only the first one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

I have multiple checkbox button elements on my page, whenever someone clicks on each of them, their color and text are changed, I was able to do that with CSS, but I wanted to change the icon in the checkbox button also, So I Use javascript in my HTML code but when I run the script it only works for one element, only the first one, so that means the icon only change for the first checkbox button but it is not working for all the other button, I tried to give all my checkbox button unique ID but I still have the same issue

This is checkbox 1 and 2 when not selected[image]

This is checkbox 1 and 2 when selected
[image]

Here's the code I run to do that:

```js
 document.getElementById ('checkbox').addEventListener ('click', function (ev) {
    document.getElementById('icon').classList[ ev.target.checked ? 'add' : 'remove'] ('fa-circle-check');
  }, false);
```

```css
.select{
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #06213B;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.select label {
  float: left; line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 26.0em; height: 4.0em;
}

.select label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.select label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */
.select label input + span{color: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */
.select input:checked + span {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.select input:checked + span{background-color: #78E821;}

input[type="checkbox"] + span:after{
  content: "Select all"; 
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after{
  content: "All selected"; 
}



.branded{
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.branded label {
  float: left; line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em; height: 4.0em;
}

.branded label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.branded label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */
.branded label input + span{color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */
.branded input:checked + span {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.branded input:checked + span{background-color: #78E821;}

.branded input[type="checkbox"] + span:after{
  content: "SELECT"; 
}

.branded input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after{
  content: "SELECTED"; 
}


.lifepoints{
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.lifepoints label {
  float: left; line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em; height: 4.0em;
}

.lifepoints label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.lifepoints label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */
.lifepoints label input + span{color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */
.lifepoints input:checked + span {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.lifepoints input:checked + span{background-color: #78E821;}

.lifepoints input[type="checkbox"] + span:after{
  content: "SELECT"; 
}

.lifepoints input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after{
  content: "SELECTED"; 
}


.mypoints{
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.mypoints label {
  float: left; line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em; height: 4.0em;
}

.mypoints label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.mypoints label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}

/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */
.mypoints label input + span{color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */
.mypoints input:checked + span {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-shadow: 0 0  0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.mypoints input:checked + span{background-color: #78E821;}

.mypoints input[type="checkbox"] + span:after{
  content: "SELECT"; 
}

.mypoints input[type="checkbox"]:checked + span:after{
  content: "SELECTED"; 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e6e078929.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<body>

 <div class="select action">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle" id="icon"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>



<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e6e078929.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<body>

 <div class="branded surveys">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle" id="icon"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
</div>

</body>
</html>


<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e6e078929.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<body>

 <div class="lifepoints">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle" id="icon"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
</div>

</body>
</html>


<html>
<head>
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6e6e078929.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!--Get your own code at fontawesome.com-->
</head>
<body>

 <div class="mypoints">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkbox"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle" id="icon"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
</div>
  
<script>
  document.getElementById ('checkbox').addEventListener ('click', function (ev) {
    document.getElementById('icon').classList[ ev.target.checked ? 'add' : 'remove'] ('fa-circle-check');
  }, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want a more organized view and to see how the code is interacting, get a look at it here:
https://codepen.io/edengandhi/pen/BaJoJYY

Comment: You cannot reuse an ID. IDs MUST be unique. Use a class and delegate

Comment: `document.getElementById('checkbox')` only targets the first element with that `id`. One should not resue `id`. Use another selector like `document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reuse an ID. IDs MUST be unique. Use a class and delegate

And you can only have ONE set of html, head and body tags

Use a class and delegate from container

I also navigate to the `i` from the closest("div") but could have used nextElementSibling instead

lastly I added selectAll functionality which was not trivial - the span is annoying If you remove the span from the `i`, then all .closest('div').querySelector('i') can be changed to .nextElementSibling

Note I am posting the complete HTML document to show you the structure
The stylesheet and script should be external

```css
.select {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #06213B;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.select label {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 26.0em;
  height: 4.0em;
}

.select label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.select label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */

.select label input+span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */

.select input:checked+span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.select input:checked+span {
  background-color: #78E821;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+span:after {
  content: "Select all";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  content: "All selected";
}

.branded {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.branded label {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em;
  height: 4.0em;
}

.branded label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.branded label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */

.branded label input+span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */

.branded input:checked+span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.branded input:checked+span {
  background-color: #78E821;
}

.branded input[type="checkbox"]+span:after {
  content: "SELECT";
}

.branded input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  content: "SELECTED";
}

.lifepoints {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.lifepoints label {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em;
  height: 4.0em;
}

.lifepoints label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.lifepoints label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */

.lifepoints label input+span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */

.lifepoints input:checked+span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.lifepoints input:checked+span {
  background-color: #78E821;
}

.lifepoints input[type="checkbox"]+span:after {
  content: "SELECT";
}

.lifepoints input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  content: "SELECTED";
}

.mypoints {
  margin: 4px;
  background-color: #3E8BB5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.mypoints label {
  float: left;
  line-height: 4.0em;
  width: 16.0em;
  height: 4.0em;
}

.mypoints label span {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px 0;
  display: block;
}

.mypoints label input {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  color: #fff !important;
}


/* selects all of the text within the input element and changes the color of the text */

.mypoints label input+span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-family: default;
}


/* This will declare how a selected input will look giving generic properties */

.mypoints input:checked+span {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/*
This following statements selects each category individually that contains an input element that is a checkbox and is checked (or selected) and chabges the background color of the span element.
*/

.mypoints input:checked+span {
  background-color: #78E821;
}

.mypoints input[type="checkbox"]+span:after {
  content: "SELECT";
}

.mypoints input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span:after {
  content: "SELECTED";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.0/css/all.min.css" />
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      const checks = document.querySelectorAll('.chk');
      const checkAll = document.getElementById('selectAll')
      document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        const tgt = e.target;
        if (tgt.matches('.chk')) {
          if (tgt.id === "selectAll") {
            tgt.closest('div').querySelector('i').classList[tgt.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('fa-circle-check');
            checks.forEach(chk => {
              chk.checked = tgt.checked
              chk.closest('div').querySelector('i').classList[chk.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('fa-circle-check');
            })
          } else {
            tgt.closest('div').querySelector('i').classList[tgt.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('fa-circle-check');
            checkAll.checked = [...checks].slice(1).every(chk => chk.checked); // check all sub checkboxes are checked
            checkAll.closest('div').querySelector('i').classList[checkAll.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('fa-circle-check');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="select action">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" id="selectAll" value="1"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
  </div>
  <div class="branded surveys">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
  </div><br clear="all" />
  <h2>Some other place</h2><br clear="all" />
  <div class="lifepoints">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
  </div><br clear="all" />
  <h2>Some other place</h2>
  <br clear="all" />
  <div class="mypoints">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="chk" value="1"><span><i class="fa-solid fa-circle"></i> &nbsp;</span>
   </label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But each of these elements are on their own section, they have each their own line of code get a look a the image how they are on my site

Comment: excellent, thank you for your code but here are 2 pictures, so you can better understand my situation, each button is separate and must have its own line of code.

picture 1 for button 1:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/24244079?key=7a1b6b04c91b9765bb4865fe00a364a4

Picture 2 for button 2:
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/24244007?key=a0755c8c2840d8be63403c5376d25de0

Comment: 1. Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have multiple HTML/HEAD/BODY tags in a page. 2. If you want to have the checkboxes in different places and not just in ONE container, change `const container = document.getElementById('container');  const container = document.getElementById('container'); const checks = container.querySelectorAll('.chk');` to `const checks = document.querySelectorAll('.chk');` then you can place the checkboxes anywhere

Comment: ok, I understand what you say, but the script can be added to only one element at a time, when I use the script on the select all button it doesn't trigger the other, and the other doesn't work too, when I add the script for them individually, they seem not to work also. They only work when they are in one container.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, I'll wait for you. Also, do you mind sharing it via codepen.io, you can still share it here if you want . However I'll wait for your help

Comment: It works like a charm, I fix my code as you suggest and everything's working properly. I really appreciate your help, thank you very much.